# Content type menu links?

Tags: routes, nodes

I'm making a site that has three different content types.  I would like a Main-Menu link to each content type.  Additionally, I would like each of these three pages to list recent nodes for that content type, with a link to to that node.  I would think this is pretty standard.

So I've created the content types, and I can click directly to each content type, but I do not know what the "best practice" would be to create these pages.  I could create an override of node--*mycontenttype*.tpl.php but is this the right way to go?  How would I link to the general page (instead of the specific node)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to do this. A simple way would be to create a view for each content type and then create menu items for each of them.

Comment: oh derp - I forgot you could create views as actual pages, not just blocks.  Thanks so much.